# How to sort mysql search result by relevance?

Tags: mysql, search, relevance

I have a similar query as asked on this question

[MySQL - How to ORDER BY RELEVANCE? INNODB Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588710/mysql-how-to-order-by-relevance-innodb-table)

Difference is, here I want to search from 5 fields as

**add1, add2, add3, post_town, post_code**

And only records in **post_code** field will be NOT EMPTY, other fields records may be empty at some places. If I search for keyword **kingston**, it returns

```
Acre Road, Kingston upon Thames, KT2 6EA

Kingston Road, Epsom, KT19 0DG

Kingston Road, Epsom, KT20 0DH
```

and these results are combination of all fields **add1, add2, add3, post_town, post_code**

I need this result in following order

```
Kingston Road, Epsom, KT19 0DG

Kingston Road, Epsom, KT20 0DH

Acre Road, Kingston upon Thames, KT2 6EA
```

My Current SQL query is like this

```
SELECT add1, add2, add3, post_town, post_code FROM address_mst 
WHERE add1 LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR add2 LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR add3 LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR post_town LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR post_code LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
```

**So I need records with search Keyword coming in the beginning would come first. How can I do that ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the prettiest but should work!

```
select a.* from (
SELECT add1, add2, add3, post_town, post_code, 1 as rank FROM address_mst 
WHERE add1 LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
UNION
SELECT add1, add2, add3, post_town, post_code, 2 as rank FROM address_mst 
WHERE add2 LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
UNION
SELECT add1, add2, add3, post_town, post_code, 3 as rank FROM address_mst 
WHERE add3 LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
UNION
SELECT add1, add2, add3, post_town, post_code, 4 as rank FROM address_mst 
WHERE post_town LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
UNION
SELECT add1, add2, add3, post_town, post_code, 5 as rank FROM address_mst 
WHERE post_code LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
) a
order by a.rank asc;
```

Comment: thank you very much, this worked perfactly. just did one modification in the last line to look it more smarter
order by a.rank asc, add1, add2, add3, post_town, post_code;

Answer (score 1):

Why not select the minimal qualifying results with query, and use own logic in the script to give advance ranking weightage to your result and sort them accordingly ?

That would help you to :

1. Have more complex ranking criteria which may or may not be possible in the query.
2. Not editing the sql query if your ranking criteria changes.

Comment: Agree. I can't help feeling that this is something that would be best solved outside of a SQL query

Answer (score 1):

For relevancy based sorting, [FULL TEXT SEARCH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) is the more reliable option.

`FULL TEXT SEARCH` used relevancy based on the number of occurrences of the searched term which could be later on used to ORDER results returned.