# Mysql search results for similar sounds

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a user table. One of a column of the table store for user first name.
Also suppose there are there rows in the table. The user first names are as follows :
'Suman','Sumon','Papiya'.
Now I want a mysql query if an user search from the table by user first name with 'Suman' then the result will shows two rows one for 'Suman' and another for 'Sumon'.

Comment: look at the fulltext searches. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Look for *SoundEx* in MySQL

Comment: fulltext won't work with "typos". searching for "suman" will return "suman". it won't return "sumon"

Comment: Have You tried to add order by name? Cuz when do where firstname like '%sum%' it sorts output data by addition. So You have to add order by firstname to get Sumon after Suman

Comment: what about using [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) ?

Comment: Look at this.examle from.here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588710/mysql-how-to-order-by-relevance-innodb-table  I use it when I want to get data by relevance (by.distance)

Comment: @SumanBiswas your question title is very confusing to get the right direction of the problem you should edit your question accordingly if you need results to match sounds of your column values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*soundex*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) it will compare if the sound of values in firstname matches to the sound of provided word

According to docs

> When using SOUNDEX(), you should be aware of the following
>   limitations:
>
> - This function, as currently implemented, is intended to work well    with strings that are in the English language only. Strings in other
>     languages may not produce reliable results.
> - This function is not guaranteed to provide consistent results with    strings that use multi-byte character sets, including utf-8.

```
select *
from t
where soundex(firstname)=soundex('Suman')
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cd321/4)