# How to query soundex() in mysql

Tags: mysql, soundex

What is the proper structure for searching within MySql using `soundex()`? I know how to produce a soundex():

```
select soundex('str');
```

just not sure how to include this in my query.

Comment: `where soundex("search_string") = soundex(search_column)`

Comment: You can see an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250267/mysql-search-results-for-similar-sounds/24250438#24250438

Comment: I have tried your suggestion pala_ with no luck; it returns no results. I have been searching with the soundex() code, for example, the soundex() code for 'Lewis' is soundex(L200). I'm assuming I search with the soundex() code rather than text or else this defeats the purpose of having a code for soundex() in the first place right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're searching for "lewis" against the `name` field of `people` table, you perform this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE soundex("lewis") = soundex(name);
```

[example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d71a/1)

Comment: That worked, thanks. But why is there a soundex() code then, e.g. SELECT SOUNDEX('Lewis')?

Comment: it's generating the codes for both the search term, AND the fields it's comparing against. eg `soundex("lewis") = L200` and `soundex("luis") = L200`. So `soundex("lewis") = soundex("luis")`  matches, whereas `"lewis" = "luis"` obviously would not. Words that "sound the same" in english should usually have the same code.

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much; I've been trying to figure this out for a long time now.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, soundex isn't designed for partials like this (e.g. `SELECT SOUNDEX('house cleaning'), SOUNDEX('house')`, which would not match), but if you would like to perform a nasty `SOUNDEX LIKE`, you could

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE SOUNDEX(column) LIKE CONCAT(SOUNDEX('partial_string'), '%')
```

You could also do

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE SOUNDEX(column) LIKE CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM SOUNDEX('hows ')), '%')
```

This "kinda" works

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
select * from table_name where soundex(column_name) = soundex('word');
```

This is a good place to read about these:http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/158-Where-is-soundex-and-other-warm-and-fuzzy-string-things.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a native way of doing this now!

You can use the syntax `SOUNDS LIKE` to do a similarity search.

```
SELECT * FROM table Where SOUNDEX(`field1`) = SOUNDEX(`field2`);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM table Where `field1` SOUNDS LIKE `field2`;
```